# Why fastforward/rewind button first time working too slow

Tags: android, roku, brightscript

I am working on video player using video node. My issue is when i press first time fastforward/rewind button during video playing/buffering then button is not working. After pressing 4-6 times fast forward or rewind button is working after that it is working properly but for first time i have to press 4-6 time button then working. My code is...

```
function setVideo()
    m.InnerVideo = m.top.createChild("InnerVideo")
    inner = createObject("RoSGNode", "ContentNode")
    inner.url = "url..."    
    inner.streamformat = "hls"

    m.innerVideo.visible = true    
    m.innerVideo.content = inner
    m.innerVideo.control = "play"
end function
```

Event handler code is...

```
function onKeyEvent(key as String, press as Boolean) as Boolean
    handled = false

    if press
        if key = "fastforward"
            print "fastforward" 

            handled = true
        end if
    end if

    return handled
end function
```

Please suggest me what should be issue? Is issue related to video file format or encoding/decoding or others?

Comment: Please provide more details, it is not clear what exactly is not working.

Comment: @ Eugene Smoliy 
I am printing a simple message like "hello" when anyone press fastforward button but its not working. After pressing 4-6 time this prints message "hello"

Comment: In this case, where is located "onKeyEvent" function? Make sure it is in Video node, because Video node handles this event and doesn't give it out.

Answer (score 0):

On onKeyEvent Function, you print above of handled = false **"?key"** value and check which value print in here. and also check **"?press"** if true then pressed key and false then not pressed. Here the Best way to whatever happening in your onKeyEvent Function. Like below

```
function onKeyEvent(key as String, press as Boolean) as Boolean

   ? "Key Event is about to execute - key = "key " press = " press 

end function
```

Answer (score 0):

If prints from `onKeyEvent` are printed after 5th or 6th time maybe You have a problem with focus. It could be that You player is not in the focus at first and then at some point You assign a focus to it.
Try to add: `m.InnerVideo.setFocus(true)` in your `setVideo()` function.
If it does not work check if there is something else that is taking the focus off the `m.InnerVideo` after `setVideo()` function is executed.